# How would I run this statement using RxJava?

Tags: android, reactive-programming, rx-java, rx-android

Rx way of doing things can be very complex for none and for many reasons...
but I feel there ARE simple ways to do simple things with RX...

How would I simply perform this statement on a background thread and receive the response on the ui thread?

All functions of this object need to run on a background thread. Get, put, clear, and delete.

```
 String city = Paper.get("city");
```

Comment: I assume `get` is a blocking function that should run on a background thread?

Comment: yes it is. all functions of that object needs to run off the ui thread...get, delete, put, clear.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The base object in Rx is `Observable`. That object usually wraps an `OnSubscribe` object, which is simply an extension of `Action1` that takes a `Subscriber` as a parameter.

What all that means is that you just need to define a class that wraps your call and passes the result to the `Subscriber`:

```
public class RxPaperGet implements Observable.OnSubscribe<String> {
    @Override
    public void call(Subscriber<? super String> t1) {
        try {
            t1.onNext(Paper.get("city"));
        } catch (Throwable t) {
            t1.onError(t);
            return;
        }
        t1.onCompleted();
    }
}
```

That's a basic example. Now, you would want to wrap that so you can call any function, and not just `Paper.get("city")`. Something like https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJavaAsyncUtil/blob/0.x/src/main/java/rx/util/async/operators/OperatorFromFunctionals.java#L44 does that, by allowing you to pass an arbitrary `Callable`.

Which in your case, would implement as:

```
Observable<String> res = OperatorFromFunctionals.fromCallable(() -> Paper.get("city"));
```

(In case you're wondering, this is java8 lambdas brought to android by retrolambda. quite nice to remove the verbosity of Rx)

Once you have your observable, you can subscribe on it, and get results. To execute on the background, and retrieve the results on the ui thread, you would do:

```
 res.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
```

`AndroidSchedulers` is provided by `rx-android`.

Then you can simply be calledback with the result:

```
.subscribe(city -> Log.d(TAG, city));
```

That returns a subscription, which is useful if you need to cancel it.

Overall:

```
OperatorFromFunctionals.fromCallable(() -> Paper.get("city"))
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .subscribe(city -> Log.d(TAG, city));
```

Comment: this is a awesome explanation! ty for ya time

Comment: I'm having a hard time using __OperatorFromFunctionals__ what is the import to bring it in the code? Its in red in Android Studio. I have rxjava dep resolved.

Comment: the package ids on maven are given on the home page of the github project, or you can simply copy the class in your project

Comment: for anyone else interested __OperatorFromFunctionals__ is contained in this dep https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJavaAsyncUtil __compile 'io.reactivex:rxjava-async-util:0.21.0'__

Comment: how do you set this up... i put this __Observable<String> ress = OperatorFromFunctionals.fromCallable(() -> Paper.get("city"));__ under my class fields and then this under onResume __res.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .subscribe(city -> Log.d(TAG, city));__. I'm getting incompatible types on the field

Comment: what is the return type of `Paper.get`?

Comment: it can be any...depending on what has been put in that location. it cant be string or object or int...

Comment: String city = Paper.get("city");
LinkedList queue = Paper.get("task-queue");
HashMap countryCodeMap = Paper.get("countries");

Comment: Paper.put("city", "Lund"); // Primitive

Comment: I assume the declaration is something like `public static T get(String key);`. I would have thought that `Observable<String>` would have sufficed, but maybe you can help the compiler by using `Paper.<String>get("city");`

Comment: i couldnt get this to work.....can you give me a complete example..to learn from.. i am a rx newbie....i

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT: This is not correct.** Will not delete the answer though to preserve the comments.

Very simple example:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    getPaper()
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(new Action1<String>() {
                @Override
                public void call(String s) {
                    Log.d("xxx", s);
                }
            });


}

private Observable<String> getPaper() {

    return Observable.just(Paper.get());
}
```

where `Paper.get()` is a long running operation that returns a `String`. Check the [docs for Scheduler](http://reactivex.io/documentation/scheduler.html).

Don't forget to observe on the main thread if you want to change the UI after receiving the result of your operation, else you will get an exception for changing the UI from outside the UI thread.

Comment: `Observable.just()` will run on the UI thread. You need to use `defer` to postpone the creation until the moment of subscription. http://blog.danlew.net/2015/07/23/deferring-observable-code-until-subscription-in-rxjava/

Comment: @LordRaydenMK I think you're mixing up to things here. just() imho has nothing to do with the thread that the operation will be running on but rather when it will be started: just() will start the operation as soon as the Observable is created, create() will start the operation only when the Observable is subscribed on. Should make no difference here because we subscribe instantly. 
Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: damn I like this simple example aswell. ty! and the subsequent explanation of just vs create

Comment: @sirvon Don't rely on my attempt on pinpointing the difference between just() and create(), I might be wrong ;)

Comment: does not work. `getPaper` is called on the ui thread, in which `Observable.just` is called, with, as parameter, the result of `Paper.get()`. The expression `Paper.get()` is evaluated before its result is passed to `just`, which means it does get called on the ui thread. To convince yourself of that, consider that this is equivalent to `String value = Paper.get(); return Observable.just(value);`.

Comment: also, `just` does not start any operation, not instantly, nor when the subscription occurs. It only takes static data (i.e. that have been computed before `just` is called). It simply serve those data to any subscription

Comment: @njzk2 I think you're right, thanks for your comment.

Comment: @sirvon when you just have one plain object, but you want an observable, for example to chain it.

Comment: @njzk2 @sivon `Observable.defer(() -> Observable.just(Paper.get())` should work

Comment: @LordRaydenMK thanks, I hadn't seen `defer`! It seems to replace `OperatorFromFunctionals` quite nicely!